# Keras fit classifier with 2 and more output classes a metric label must be specified

Tags: scikit-learn, keras

while trying to fit a classifier (using the KerasWrapper from sklearn, i.e. `from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier`), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extArgExtraction.py", line 915, in <module>
a, p, r, f = evaluatePositionOnlyNeural(matrix, numIterations)
  File "extArgExtraction.py", line 367, in evaluatePositionOnlyNeural
classifier.fit(X, Y, class_weight=class_weights)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py", line 210, in fit
return super(KerasClassifier, self).fit(x, y, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py", line 141, in fit
self.model = self.build_fn(**self.filter_sk_params(self.build_fn))
  File "extArgExtraction.py", line 493, in create_baseline_model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['categorical_accuracy', keras_metrics.precision(), keras_metrics.recall(), keras_metrics.f1_score()]) # perhaps this should not be binary (but categorical instead)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 440, in compile
handle_metrics(output_metrics)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 409, in handle_metrics
mask=masks[i])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 403, in weighted
score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras_metrics/metrics.py", line 213, in __call__
tp = self.tp(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras_metrics/metrics.py", line 70, in __call__
y_true, y_pred = self.cast(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras_metrics/metrics.py", line 24, in cast
return self.cast_strategy(y_true, y_pred, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras_metrics/metrics.py", line 46, in _categorical
raise ValueError("With 2 and more output classes a "

ValueError: With 2 and more output classes a metric label must be specified
```

Relevant piece of code:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.array(nmatrix), columns=None)
ds = df.values
X = ds[:,0:numpy.shape(df)[1]-1].astype(float)
Y = to_categorical(numpy.array(labels))#numpy.reshape(numpy.array(labels), len(labels), 1))

classifier.fit(X, Y)#, class_weight=class_weights)
```

I cannot find this error anywhere (on google). Anyone any ideas on how to specify a metric label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most relevant line here is this:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adam', 
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy', 
                       keras_metrics.precision(), 
                       keras_metrics.recall(), 
                       keras_metrics.f1_score()])
```

You see `'precision'`, `'recall'` and consequently `'f1_score'` are calculated from true positives, true negatives, false positives, false negatives.

So in a multi-class setting, how will you calculate that the specified prediction is a true positive or false positive or other? For that you need to specify the positive label (class which you want to consider positive).

You need to change your code to:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adam', 
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy', 
                       keras_metrics.precision(label=class_value), 
                       keras_metrics.recall(label=class_value), 
                       keras_metrics.f1_score(label=class_value)])
```

where `class_value` is your class that you want to be considered positive. All other classes will be considered negatives.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!